Xamarin Forms: Vimeo ExtractConfiguration: System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (Authentication failed, see inner exception.)
I am using below codes to Extract different Configuration of a Vimeo video.
ExtractConfiguration("https://player.vimeo.com/video/431550943/config");

public  void ExtractConfiguration(string vimeoUrl)
{
    try
    {
        using (var objClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string strResponse = objClient.DownloadString(vimeoUrl);
            VimeoConfig vimeoConfig = new VimeoConfig();
            vimeoConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VimeoConfig>(strResponse.ToString());
            if(vimeoConfig.request.files.progressive.Count != 0)
            {
                string url = vimeoConfig.request.files.progressive[0].url;
                CrossMediaManager.Current.Speed = 1F;
                //UI actions
            }
            else
            {
                //UI actions
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ExtractConfiguration Exception:>>" + e);
    }
}

The above code was working fine before and now I am getting below exception:

System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (Authentication failed, see inner exception.) ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00042] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/MonoBtlsContext.cs:220
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:715
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:289
at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:223
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0025c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:310
at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Net.WebConnectionTunnel tunnel, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0016a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoTlsStream.cs:137
at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.WebOperation operation, System.Boolean reused, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00170] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:236
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.WebOperation operation, System.Boolean reused, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00208] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:248
at System.Net.WebConnection.InitConnection (System.Net.WebOperation operation, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000f7] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:277
at System.Net.WebOperation.Run () [0x00052] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebOperation.cs:268
at System.Net.WebCompletionSource1[T].WaitForCompletion () [0x0008e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebCompletionSource.cs:111  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.RunWithTimeoutWorker[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[TResult] workerTask, System.Int32 timeout, System.Action abort, System.Func`1[TResult] aborted, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts) [0x000e8] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:956
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1218
at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs:249
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.IO.Stream writeStream) [0x000e6] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs:850
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal (System.Uri address, System.Net.WebRequest& request) [0x00061] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs:302
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString (System.Uri address) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs:684
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString (System.String address) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs:674
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(string)
at MyProjectName.Views.VideoDetailPage.ExtractConfiguration (System.String vimeoUrl) [0x00009] in <2d25509d562b4b7ebdeab1e0d9398c29>:0

I don't know what is the exact usage of this code, I think with this we get the less size video link. Someone else did this before me.

there is a problem with the server certificate

@Jason What problem and how we can fix it?
